# Can I turn vw into pixels (or rand() friendly units) for use in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I am using a starfield generator from codepen. Inside of it, there is a portion of code that defines the 'box' within which the starfield sits.

```
    $bxshadow: append(
      $bxshadow,
      (random(7680) + 0px) (random(4320) + 0px) #fff,
      comma
    );
  }
```

I have put "7860" and "4320" in to handle just about any monitor I can imagine, and picked starfield density that looks good at that size.

This seems crude to me, though. It seems like it would be better to pass in 100vw into the code, but it doesn't work because rand() only takes numbers. I tried a variable with:

```
$widthvar: calc(100vw);

@for $i from 1 to $stars {
    $bxshadow: append(
      $bxshadow,
      (random($widthvar) + 0px) (random(4320) + 0px) #fff,
      comma
    );
  }
```

But no dice.

Is it possible to return 100vw or 100% as a number that can rand() can use? Is there an alternative to rand() for possibly iterating across the screen at pseudorandom intervals? I would use this to define both the starfield area and the number of stars to generate.

For reference, if it is relevant, here is a [link to](https://codepen.io/amiangie/pen/RRdQAb) and the SCSS of the full Pen on which my project is based:

```
html,
body { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}  
body {
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#094c72+98,01293f+100 */
    background: rgb(9,76,114);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom, ellipse cover,  rgb(9,76,114) 0%,rgb(1,41,63) 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, rgb(9,76,114) 0%, rgb(1,41,63) 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom, ellipse, rgb(9,76,114) 0%, rgb(1,41,63) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom,  rgb(9,76,114) 0%,rgb(1,41,63) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#094c72', endColorstr='#01293f',GradientType=1 );
}

@function box-shadow($stars) {
    $bxshadow: ();
    @for $i from 1 to $stars {
        $bxshadow: append($bxshadow, (random(2000) + 0px) (random(2000) + 0px) #fff, comma);
    }
    @return unquote($bxshadow);
}

$bxshadow-large: box-shadow(300);
$bxshadow-medium: box-shadow(500);
$bxshadow-small: box-shadow(800);

.stars.large {
    height: 3px;
    width: 3px;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: $bxshadow-large;
    animation: blink-large 7s infinite;
}
.stars.medium {
    height: 2px;
    width: 2px;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: $bxshadow-medium;
    animation: blink-medium 5s infinite;
}
.stars.small {
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: $bxshadow-small;
    animation: blink-small 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink-large {
    0% {
        box-shadow: $bxshadow-large;
    }   
    70% {
        $colors: '#fff', 'transparent';
        $stars: $bxshadow-large;
        @for $i from 1 to length($stars) {
            $star: set-nth(nth($stars, $i), 3, unquote(nth($colors, random(length($colors)))));
            $stars: set-nth($stars, $i, $star);
        }
        box-shadow: $stars;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: $bxshadow-large;
    }
}
@keyframes blink-medium {
    0% {
        box-shadow: $bxshadow-medium;
    }   
    70% {
        $colors: '#fff', 'transparent';
        $stars: $bxshadow-medium;
        @for $i from 1 to length($stars) {
            $star: set-nth(nth($stars, $i), 3, unquote(nth($colors, random(length($colors)))));
            $stars: set-nth($stars, $i, $star);
        }
        box-shadow: $stars;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: $bxshadow-medium;
    }
}
@keyframes blink-small {
    0% {
        box-shadow: $bxshadow-small;
    }   
    70% {
        $colors: '#fff', 'transparent';
        $stars: $bxshadow-small;
        @for $i from 1 to length($stars) {
            $star: set-nth(nth($stars, $i), 3, unquote(nth($colors, random(length($colors)))));
            $stars: set-nth($stars, $i, $star);
        }
        box-shadow: $stars;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: $bxshadow-small;
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to dynamicly generate different numbers of shadows/stars depending on the viewport-width?
It sounds for me that it is not possible with pure css/sass

Comment: It's okay if it's only set once, and never changed. Is that still too tall of an order for sass? I thought that if it wasn't updating on resize, it wouldn't call for Javascript.